# What is the significance of 64KB in terms of disc IO and is this relevant in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hardware, hard-drive

I'm looking at a [node.js library (gen-readlines)](https://github.com/neurosnap/gen-readlines) that reads large flat files via a generator - i.e. a file is read in 'chunks' of 65 536 bytes at a time via a generator.

Not having a CS background I didn't think much about this until someone mentioned that a disk reads 65 536 bytes of data at a time.

***Questions:***

1. Is this true of all disks (both metallic and SSD)?
2. 8 bytes == 64 bit. What is the relationship between a 64 bit processor and a disk read of 64bits * 1024 bytes read sizes?
3. i.e. what is the significance of 64KB in terms of Disc IO?
4. Considering how high-level JavaScript is, can I really instruct a generator to `yield` bytes after exactly one disc read? Or is the number specified as a buffer size in the library I've linked to completely arbitrary when thinking in terms of JavaScript...

Comment: 65536 is 2^16 — it's common for disk blocks to be sized as a power of 2, and 65536 is a comfortable size for grabbing multiple disk blocks (which are probably 4096 bytes in size each). Generally a language like JavaScript is just guessing at an efficient block size, but that's not a *bad* guess.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy. What do you mean by 'disk blocks to be sized'? It's a little off-topic from the question, but I'd like to find out more. How is sizing determined obtained in a disk?

Comment: It's just the way disks (and SSDs now) work. The interface between the drive and the computer operates on blocks, and blocks of some fixed size. Back in the day disk blocks were generally 512 bytes (2^9), but now 4096 (2^12) is more common. Whether that statement someone made about disks always reading 64K at time is true or not, I doubt; it totally depends on the OS and the hardware.

Comment: @Pointy: Today, 64k is common. It's 4k that's "back in the day." 512 bytes is back in the days of my *youth*, dimly-remembered now. ;-)

Comment: Wow I'm old I guess. I guess that makes sense in a world where 2TB disks are almost literally a dime a dozen.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well be that as it may but my Linux laptop *claims* the drive is uniformly formatted with 4096 byte blocks, though I suppose the OS may layer that on top of the larger physical block size.

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah, the OS and separately the drive controller may both be lying. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this true of all disks (both metallic and SSD)?

No, it depends on how the disk is formatted, the [cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cluster) size IIRC. It is a fairly common value in today's world, but smaller cluster sizes aren't *un*common. They are typically multiples of 4k (in the last decade or more). When I was young and the world was new, 512 bytes was normal. :-) 64k is likely to be big enough for even a disk formatted with a large cluster size.

But there's a lot more to it than the basic unit of disk allocation. For one thing, there's very likely multiple levels of caching — in the disk drive's built-in controller, in the disk controller on the motherboard, in the OS... Today's disks (or even yesterday's, or the day before's) are not stupid platters we have to try to micro-manage with code.

> 8 bytes == 64 bit. What is the relationship between a 64 bit processor and a disk read of 64bits * 1024 bytes read sizes?

Other than that they're both powers of 2, I don't think there is one.

> Considering how high-level JavaScript is, can I really instruct a generator to yield bytes after exactly one disc read?

That's not really the key question. The key question is whether the code *in* the generator function (or any function) can read exactly 64k at a time.

The answer is yes, and that code does:

```
let bytesRead = fs.readSync(fd, readChunk, 0, bufferSize, position);
```

...where `bufferSize` is 64k. `readSync` is a low-level call.

In summary: 64k is likely to be large enough to hold even the largest minimum allocation unit of a disk; and if it's too big, no problem, it's still not outrageous and multiple allocation units can be read into it. But I'd want to see well-crafted benchmarks before I believed it made a significant difference. I can see the logic, but with the layers between even Node's C++ code inside `readSync` and the actual physical reading of the disk...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What does a 'low-level call' mean? One of the other answers below mentions that that disc access may be aligned... Is that along the same lines? i.e. that readSync is passed along to the operation system as is?

Comment: @ZachSmith: Largely as-is, yes. Node tries to map I/O operations to the equivalent system call as closely as it can.

Answer (score 2):

While disk read may be aligned, the OS makes it transparent for the most part; as you mentioned that you're reading sequentially, it doesn't matter what buffer size you're using. There are no relationship between 64 bit and 64KB alignment (I have only heard of 4K align anyway).

You may want to create a buffer of size of power of 2; just for better aligning with memory allocator. JavaScript abstracts most of the memory allocations, so it doesn't necessary improves performance when you have a 64K or 4K buffer (in normal sense, it should be sufficiently big to reduce syscall overhead).

Do the IO in your favorite style, as long as it is buffered. The buffer size doesn't matter too much if it's 4K or 64K (but too small buffer is bad as unbuffered), but whether the IO is buffered or not, matters very much.

Answer (score 1):

1- no, it depends on the firmware of the storage device, on the drive controller, and on the operating system. Newer HDDs use 4 KiB sectors, thus such a disk reads at least 4 KiB at a time.

2- there is no relation between the processor's register or bus size and the disk I/O chunks.

3- data rates depend on both data size and  I/O latency overhead (overhead due to I/O processing, for instance system call processing). Bigger data chunks means less I/O for the same data size, means less I/O overhead.

4- from the point of view at the JavaScript high layer, you do not need to worry about these low-level behaviours. Everything will work correctly, since there are many caches at several levels.